# Making a website like youtube

Tags: html, youtube, web

So I am kind of making like a private website right now but I am making a website that is similar like youtube but how can I make it so it can make a new page (Also file). I am kind of new at html but now completely noob. I know some codes like linking and passage but never knew how to make a website where users can upload there content.

Also I want to know how I can make a website where you can make people like sign in as well.

-I will really appreciate it, thx!!!

**Edited:** Actually I made a youtube website type thing so never mind.

Comment: There are lots of tutorials available in google and **YouTube** too. https://www.google.co.in/search?q=how+to+make+website+like+youtube+in+php&oq=how+to+make+website+like+you&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j0l3.11251j0j7&client=ms-android-micromax&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 2):

You can use server side languages like ruby on rails, PHP, Ajax, Javascript, etc to add some depth to it. Inorder to store the user data and other databases, you can use mySQL or Microsoft SQL server or Oracle SQL server... Javasript can help you to make your web more dynamic. You can also use VisualStudio. You can find all of this in it

Comment: You should add Angular, React/Redux, Aurelia and ASP.NET Core 2.0 into this mix of technologies just to round out this sweet answer. :)